# Searching and saving books from Amazon with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-product-api

I just started coding with Ruby on rails, and I am currently trying to make an app, a search engine that finds books sold on Amazon. I also want users to be able to save books to their profiles, e.g. a wish list.

I know there are a lot of gems out there (amazon-ecs', vacuum, etc.), but I am struggling to make any sense of the documentation. I am looking for a step by step guide, from installing the gem, to what code to put in what files etc.

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: if this is your first ruby project, drop rails for the moment and do some basic stuff, you'd better search something easier too, what you want needs authentication and is imho not beginner stuff

Comment: As peter told, if its your beginning of RoR better start with something easy to understand rails and ruby. Build some blog or todo's i know thats boring stuff but they are super examples of RoR development CRUD. After that try to build some in pure Ruby (some game?). After that i think you will understand code, and can build some project yourself. First build some MVP and then you can make it bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your tips :) I have build some easy blog apps, and a basic social media app. But since i cant make any sense of the gem documentation, I guess I need to do som more work first. It would be nice to have a step by step guide for future ref, anyway :)